# Auto redeploy on iOS Simulator XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, installation

Is there any way to [edit] have a fresh [/edit] redeploy your app from xcode onto the iOS simulator when you hit run, without have to delete [edit] the existing data from the app [/edit] every time?

Comment: Why would you delete it every time? It only makes sense to delete your app from simulator if you're testing how brand new installation behaves (ie: testing if your default NSUserDefault setting works...). Otherwise there's no need to delete app befoer each run.

Comment: Right, I meant to say that I would like it to mimic a fresh install, will cleared data and user settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to delete it every time… you should just be able to hit run and it will overwrite or otherwise update the version that is loaded there.

I normally have a debug button to remove all data and add in fake data if necessary and wrap them in a `DEBUG` flag. This allows me to control it without having to restart the app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    #if DEBUG
        // Make Button and hook it to clearAllData
    #endif
}

- (void)clearAllData
{
    // Clear the Core Data databases
    SDAppDelegate *myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [myDelegate clearAllData];

    // Clear the UserDefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

    // Run the initial Setup again
    [self setup];
}
```

Comment: I assume @sringer means deploy in a way that wipes all of the app's local data?

Comment: Correct ^ sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. In that case I've updated my answer with my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to start with empty data each time, you can use the Xcode organizer to take an application data snapshot of a freshly started app, add the snapshot to your project and then edit your scheme and go to Run -> Options and select the snapshot in from the Application Data popup menu. That way when the app is started, it always starts with the same, presumably empty, data.

I don't think it clears NSUserDefaults, though.

Comment: Is there a way to clear NSUserDefaults without having to delete the app?